# Excel(or Numbers) formular to replace new line '\n' with something else for Core Data?

Tags: csv, newline, spreadsheet

I need to convert a spreadsheet(in xls format) to CSV file and import it to Core Data, the spreadsheet has a field that contains new line character(entered by Alt+Enter on Windows or Option+Command+Enter on Mac), but when I convert it to CSV, I assume I'll lose all the new line characters? If so, I need to replace the '\n' in the text to something else, can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Say if I have a column B and I want column C to be the converted text, so for column C what should I set in the top field?

Or is there any different way to do this?

Thanks!

edit:

I found that there is a SUBSTITUTE formula but I don't know how to enter the new line character, and I found on Windows Excel you can do this by Alt+0100(numpad), the problem is I only have a Mac ;-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be explained here:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/05/28/find-and-replace-line-breaks-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Ctrl+H in Excel to Find and Replace "\n" with whatever characters you need? If you want it blank, just replce by blank field in the "Replace With" field.